# Does the expression $\frac{1}{(1-hL)}$ have an upper bound?

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Considering that $1+hL\leq e^{Lh}$, is there an expression that bounds $\frac{1}{(1-hL)}$ from above in a similar fassion? If not, what are some other identities I can try?

Comment: Which variable is unlimited?  If it is $h$, consider that $h\approx \frac 1L$ makes the total quantity in question unlimited...

Comment: What do we know about the size of $hL$?

Comment: On what domain? Do you want a linear bound? For $x>1$, where the values are all negative, $x-3$ is an upper bound.

Comment: hL is going to be very small so the expression in question remains positive. L is just a constant obtained from the Lipschitz condition and h is a time step

Comment: You can use $$
\frac{1}{{1 - x}} < 1 + ax < e^{ax} 
$$ for $0 < x < 1 - \frac{1}{a}$ with $a>0$.

Comment: I need it to be less than or equal to, can you think of a function that can give this?

Comment: Can I use ln(x-1)? I think that might be suitable

Comment: What is $\ln(x-1)$ for small $x$?

Comment: I checked the graphs, ln(x-1) stays above 1/(1-x) for the regions we are aiming for